# How to do customer data instead of json from the link (stockchart)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, highcharts

Referred [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/compare/)   link and having doubt with this code `{$.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=' + name.toLowerCase() + '-c.json&callback=?'}`,
I have Json data, if i replace instead of JSON link in the stockchart,chart get disappeared. If have only from last month,the chart should display from the last month. I don't know how to replace the link with my data. And i have 2 series, can I change to line to bar in stock highcharts to column?
Please share the points for 2 series column charts with the data from server side.
I have tried,replaced the link with my server side data.

```
 var data1=([1501545600000,150.05],[1501632000000,157.14],[1501718400000,155.57],[1501804800000,156.39],[1502064000000,158.81],[1502150400000,160.08],[1502236800000,161.06],[1502323200000,155.32],[1502409600000,157.48],[1502668800000,159.85],                [1502755200000,161.60],[1502841600000,160.95],[1502928000000,157.86],[1503014400000,157.50],[1503273600000,157.21],[1503360000000,159.78],[1503446400000,159.98],[1503532800000,159.27],[1503619200000,159.86]);
            var data2=([1504224000000,164.05],[1504569600000,162.08],[1504656000000,161.91],[1504742400000,161.26],[1504828800000,158.63],[1505088000000,161.50],[1505174400000,160.86],[1505260800000,159.65],[1505347200000,158.28],[1505433600000,159.88],[1505692800000,158.67],[1505779200000,158.73],[1505865600000,156.07],[1505952000000,153.39],[1506038400000,151.89],[1506297600000,150.55],[1506384000000,153.14]);
            var startDate  = new Date("April 01, 2016 00:00:00");
            var today = new Date();

            var count =  parseInt((today.getTime() - startDate)/(24*3600*1000)) -1;

            $.getJSON(data1, function (data1) {

                // Create the chart
                Highcharts.stockChart('ytdChart', {
                    chart: {
                        alignTicks: false
                        //type:column
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        range: 9 * 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 // nine months
                    },
                    rangeSelector : {
                        enabled:false,

                    },
                    navigator: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'YTD'
                    },
                    scrollbar: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    series: [{
                        // type: 'column',
                        name: 'YTD monthly charge',
                        data: data1,
                        tooltip: {
                            valueDecimals: 2
                        }
                    }
                    //{
                        //type:column,
                     //   name: 'YTD Total',
                     //   data: data2,
                     //   tooltip: {
                     //       valueDecimals: 2
                    //    }
                    }

                    ]
                });
            });
```

Comment: compare [this](https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=msft-c.json) with your server side data are they same

Comment: Yes. I took for last 2 months from the same link you assigned to a variable and instead of json link,replaced the assigned variable,its not working.

Comment: I ve posted the coding in my post, If u give solution for 2 series, its more helpful.

Comment: something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8ftbo807/)

Comment: Place your data somewhere on server. Take a look at the example below (I used https://www.json-generator.com/ to generate exemplary JSON file). Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ba91233b/.

Comment: Ok,thank you. I want to give 2 datas for month. But even if we give 2 data,why it takes the 2nd data for sep (from ur sample @d_paul ). Can you please help me out?